# How to insert or replace using adapter.Update(datatable) my table contain primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

i am importing data from excel and creating data table and inserting in SQLite database but if data already exist i want it replace. doing this one by one take 1 minute for 2000 row so i am doing through  datatable adapter.Update(datatable) but it show error if table already exist

my Code is:

```
      conn.Open();
          using (var transaction = conn_cms.BeginTransaction())
          {
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM 
                                             {0}",DT.TableName);
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
            SQLiteCommandBuilder builder = new 
            SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Update(DT);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: I have never used SQLite, so forgive me if I am wrong, but can you not upload into a (by definition empty) temporary table and then perform an upsert from within SQLite?

Comment: Thank You so much  @jonathan  it's good idea if i will not find another way via adapter.Update(datatable) or similar directly way. i will try this..thanks man.